# Boundedness of an Integral Operator with kernel differentiable

Tags: functional-analysis

I do not understand how to prove the $L^2$ boundedness of an operator.

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{C}$ an open bounded subset with $C^{\infty}$ boundary $b\Omega$. Let $A:b\Omega\times b\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ an infinite differentiable function. Define

$$Tu(z):=\int_{\xi\in b\Omega}A(z,\xi)u(\xi)d\xi, \hspace{0.3cm}z\in b\Omega$$

Then prove that $T$ sends $L^2(b\Omega)$ roundly into $C^{\infty}(b\Omega)$. Why?

My try: As $A$ is a infinite differentiable function, we can find $M>0$ such that $|A(z,\xi)|\leq M$ for all $x,\xi$. (?) If this is true, then

$$\int_{b\Omega}|Tu(z)|^2dz=\int_{b\Omega}\left(\int_{\xi\in b\Omega}A(z,\xi)u(\xi)d\xi\right)^2dz\leq \int_{b\Omega}\left(\int_{\xi\in b\Omega}|A(z,\xi)||u(\xi)|d\xi\right)^2dz\leq M^2\int_{b\Omega}\left(\int_{\xi\in b\Omega}|u(\xi)|d\xi\right)^2dz$$

Now, applying Hölder inequality, we get

$$\int_{b\Omega}|Tu(z)|^2dz\leq M^2\int_{b\Omega}\left(\int_{\xi\in b\Omega}|u(\xi)|d\xi\right)^2dz\leq M^2\mu(b\Omega)\int_{\xi\in b\Omega}\int_{\xi\in b\Omega}|u(\xi)|^2d\xi dz=M^2\mu(b\Omega)^2||u||_{L^2(b\Omega)}$$

Am I right?
If it is the case, what happens if $\Omega$ is not bounded? For example, a cone in $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Anyone could confirm this? :/